# phpMyAdmin logs-off after default 1440 seconds, though all settings seems fine

Tags: php.ini

Following are set and confirmed:

- I've set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity'] = 259200;` in `config.inc.php`,
- I've set `session.gc_maxlifetime = 259200` in `php.ini`,
- I see value `259200` in `Settings > Features > General` tab, in `Login cookie validity` field, in phpMyAdmin.

And even so, my phpMyAdmin logs-off automatically, with message, that there was no action for past 1440 seconds (default pMA's value) and re-login is required. So, it still ignores my setting of `259200` seconds (three days).

What other settings or factors may influence this behavior?

**EDIT**: *I'm using XAMPP for Windows, and I've observed this behavior only on one of my computers, though I'm using exactly the same settings set (entire XAMPP unpacked from common `.zip` file) on my every machine (other computers keeps pMA session for 3 days. This makes case even more suspicious.*

Comment: While you change cookie settings I don't think your phpMyAdmin is set to use them and is still using session instead.

Comment: @edvinas.me Are you talking about `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` param? It is set to `'cookie'` in my case, so I think, my pMA IS using cookies.

Comment: Did you restart apache, not mysqld?

Comment: @symlynk Of course! :]

Answer (score 0):

For those, struggling the same problem.

The `LoginCookieValidity` is **system-wide** setting, not per-server one. So it have to be specified as `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']`, not as `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity']`.

Plus, standard cases, mentioned by *edvinas.me* and *symlynk* in the comments: make sure, that you set phpMyAdmin to use cookies (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` param set to `cookie`) and that you restart Apache after all the changes to configruation files are saved.